# Recommender systems with Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, data-science, recommendation-engine

Please how can I build a recommender system that recommends feeds/posts to users with the Keras framework. I already tried using Term frequency but I just want a better algorithm.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please post more of your code for better answers.

You can try cosine similarity measures to output your predictions.

Try implementing `Matrix Factorization` algorithms like `svd`. Or use very good implementations from the `surprise` library.

Try using `RNN` to get more out of your Feed/Posts or use `K-Means Clustering`.